# How to select single record with Linq?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

i have this table

```
**ID           CityCode             Price**
```

---

```
1             ABB                  100
2             CAB                  160
3             CAB                  340
4             TRE                  800
5             ABB                  770
6             TRE                  900
7             ABB                  500
```

I want write down a query(linq) which will return the following result as show the code below

```
CityCode
```

---

```
   ABB
   CAB
   TRE
```

i want select a list with only the CityCode without duplicate record, How can i do it with linq to sql ?

Thanks so much for your attention,

have a good time,
Cheers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like you want `Distinct()`

```
var cityCodes = cities.Select(x => x.CityCode).Distinct();
```

That's not the same as retrieving a single record (as per your title) though. If this isn't what you're after, please give us more information.

Comment: Pheww that was lightning fast ..(i think he meant single as in the value should appear only once/single in the list)

Comment: Thanks so much it works perfectly ...and thanks to StackOverflow group always available to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using .Distinct():

```
var city = (from ci in dc.citieis select ci.CityCode).Distinct();
```

I hope this is what you're looking for; please try to make your question more explainatory. For more on LINQ you can checkout my blog here : [linqtoSQL](http://wahabkotwal.blogspot.com/2011/05/taste-of-linq-to-sql.html)